# der Montag oder Montag

Tags: article, proper-noun

Zoo: Die Tage der Woche wurden hinsichtlich der Besucheranzahl miteinander verglichen. ***Der*** Montag ist an der ersten Stelle.

Sollte man in diesem Fall einen Artikel vor "Montag" setzen?

Comment: Bei solchen Zitaten wäre es immer schön, auch die Quelle zu erfahren. War das ein Zoo im Hamburg, in Dresden, in Köln, in Wien oder in Zürich? Die deutsche Sprache weist in vielen Aspekten manchmal erhebliche geographische Unterschiede auf, die man möglicherweise berücksichtigen müsste, wenn man diese Frage beantworten will.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde hier den Artikel benutzen, analog zu "der Februar", "der Frühling" oder "der Nachmittag", aber es klingt bei Wochentagen aus irgendwelchen Gründen zumindest für meine norddeutsch geprägten Ohren auch ohne Artikel nicht falsch, wenn auch weniger elegant.

> Die Wochentage wurden verglichen. [Der] Montag steht an erster Stelle.
> Die Feiertage wurden verglichen. Ostern steht an erster Stelle. *(nur ohne Artikel möglich)*
> Die Jahreszeiten wurden verglichen. Der Sommer steht an erster Stelle. *(nur mit Artikel möglich)*

Auch für Zeitangaben kann man einfach den Namen des Wochentags benutzen, was bei den meisten anderen Zeitangaben nicht funktioniert. Dazu muss aber aus dem Kontext klar sein, *welcher* Tag gemeint ist, z.B.der nächste oder letzte Montag.

> Wir treffen uns Montag. Wir treffen uns nächsten Montag. Wir treffen uns am Montag.

> Sonntag gehen wir in den Zoo.

> Montag war ich krank.

https://blog.leo.org/2019/11/12/sind-die-wochentage-eigennamen/

Comment: +1.Aber eben genauso richtig: wir treffen uns am Montag.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, ob das wieder etwas ist, dass für den Süden (für Österreich) spezifisch ist, aber im Osten Österreichs würd niemand sagen »Wir treffen uns Montag« auch nicht »Sonntag gehen wir in den Zoo.« Das klingt ziemlich deutsch (im Sinn von: deutschländisch; wäre ich Bayer würde ich sagen: preußisch). Stattdessen wird bei uns in solchen Konstruktionen dem Wochentag immer ein »am« vorangestellt: »Wir treffen uns am Montag« und »Am Sonntag gehen wir in den Zoo.« Ich empfinde das Weglassen von »am« in diesen Sätzen als falsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "Wir treffen uns Montag" ist auch im Deutschen falsch. Richtig sind "Wir treffen uns am Montag" und "Wir treffen uns montags". Man sagt ja auch nicht, "Wir treffen uns Bahnhof". Gibt sicher jemanden, der das grammatisch erklären kann (Subtantiv braucht Präposition, oder so), jedenfalls ist es auch nicht "deutschländisch".

Comment: @Ben: Meintest du mit »im Deutschen« eigentlich »in Deutschland«? Denn wir in Österreich sprechen auch Deutsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ups, ja, da hab ich mich vertan. Leider kann ich den Kommentar nicht mehr bearbeiten. Entschuldigung.

Comment: @Ben:  "Wir treffen uns Montag" ist auch im Deutschen falsch." Diese Behauptung ist falsch. "Wir sehen uns Montag" ist hier genauso richtig wie "Wir haben uns gestern gesehen" und "Wir sehen uns morgen." Und jetzt? Bist du irgendwie mehr Muttersprachler als ich? Oder steht das irgendwo, wo man es glauben kann?

Comment: Ich habe einen Link hinzugefügt.

Comment: @HalvarF Vergleiche "[wir sehen uns (am) Montag](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wir+sehen+uns+Montag%2CWir+sehen+uns+am+Montag&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2019&smoothing=3)" mit "[wir treffen uns am Montag](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wir+treffen+uns+Montag%2CWir+treffen+uns+am+Montag&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2019&smoothing=3)".

Comment: @Ben Der erste Link zeigt, dass selbst in gedruckten Büchern beide in Gebrauch sind. Na also.

Comment: @HalvarF Der erste Link zeigt, dass **mit *sehen*** beide Formen in Gebrauch sind, der zweite Link zeigt jedoch, dass **bei *treffen*** – das du in deinem Beispiel verwendest – nur die Form mit *am* verwendet wird! Ich habe dir also belegt, dass deine Form in der deutschen Schriftsprache zumindest ungebräuchlich ist, und nicht nur mein Sprachgefühl, sondern das der meisten anderen Sprecher auch, deine Verwendung (mit *treffen* und ohne *am*) als falsch empfindet.